# VB.NET Count number of files to copy with WebClient

Tags: arrays, vb.net, webclient

I'm trying to write a code that copy files from a folder to another folder with a progress bar and with a `Label` that count files, like `Copying 0 files of 10 files`. but my code is not working and throws and error.

`Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.`

this is my code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Public Class Form1

Dim filesToCopy As New ArrayList()
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    CopyBtn.Text = "Copy File"
    CopyBtn.Parent = Me
    ProgBar.Left = CopyBtn.Right
End Sub
Dim WithEvents CopyBtn As New Button
Dim ProgBar As New ProgressBar
Dim WithEvents FileCopier As New WebClient
Public Sub check(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles CopyBtn.Click

    Dim src As String = "D:\test"
    Dim dest As String = "D:\test2"

    For Each Dir As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(src)
        Dim dirInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Dir)
        If Not System.IO.File.Exists(dest & "\" & dirInfo.Name) Then
            filesToCopy.Add(dirInfo.Name)
        End If
    Next

    If filesToCopy.Count > 0 Then
        If MsgBox("There are new files found. Do you want to sync it now?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirm") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            For i = 0 To filesToCopy.Count - 1
                Dim FileCopier As WebClient = New WebClient
                AddHandler FileCopier.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf FileCopier_DownloadProgressChanged
                AddHandler FileCopier.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf FileCopier_DownloadFileCompleted

                CopyBtn.Enabled = False
                ProgBar.Parent = Me
                FileCopier.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(src & "\" & filesToCopy(i)), dest & "\" & filesToCopy(i))

            Next
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("No new files to be copied")
    End If
End Sub
```

this is my code that tracks the number of files copying.

```
Private Sub FileCopier_DownloadProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles FileCopier.DownloadProgressChanged
    ProgBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

    For Each file In filesToCopy
        total += filesToCopy.Add(file)
    Next

    Label2.Text = total \ filesToCopy.Count
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it here instead in *DownloadProgressChanged*

```
   For i = 0 To filesToCopy.Count - 1
            Dim FileCopier As WebClient = New WebClient
            AddHandler FileCopier.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf FileCopier_DownloadProgressChanged
            AddHandler FileCopier.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf FileCopier_DownloadFileCompleted

        CopyBtn.Enabled = False
        ProgBar.Parent = Me
        FileCopier.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(src & "\" & filesToCopy(i)), dest & "\" & filesToCopy(i))
        Label2.Text = i + 1 & "/" & FilesToCopy.Count 'PUT IT HERE INSTEAD

    Next
```

Comment: it works, but I have 6 files to be copied but it stops at 5? like `5/6` why did it happen?

Comment: It should be i + 1.. I forgot that your loop starts with 0. Edited my code already. And btw it's nice to see you're using the code I gave you. :D

Comment: Now it works perfectly! :) Again, Thanks A LOT! :) I really appreciate your efforts helping me :), yeah because that code saved my life :) for my future reference too. :)